# any efficient way to spread the list names to its inside vectors?

Tags: r

Given a list `lst <- list(a = 1:2, b = 3:5)` looking like

```
> lst
$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 3 4 5
```

I want to spread the name `a` and `b` for the values in `lst$a` and `lst$b`, such that

```
> lst
$a
a a 
1 2 

$b
b b b 
3 4 5
```

My stupid code to make it is something like below:

```
lst[] <-lapply(seq(lst),function(k) lst[[k]] <- setNames(lst[[k]], rep(names(lst[k]),length(lst[[k]]))))
```

but I suspect there might be other smarter and more elegant way to do it. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I know you are happy with the accepted answer already but out of curiosity, I included the new answers in my benchmark. Have a look if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try:

```
Map(setNames, lst, Map(rep, names(lst), lengths(lst)))

$a
a a 
1 2 

$b
b b b 
3 4 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Define a custom function with two arguments

```
f <- function(x, y) setNames(x, rep(y, times = length(x)))
```

And use `Map`

```
Map(f, lst, names(lst))
```

Result

```
#$a
#a a 
#1 2 
#
#$b
#b b b 
#3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this directly as well without apply family or `for` loop

```
vals <- rep(names(lst), lengths(lst))
split(setNames(unlist(lst), vals), vals)

#$a
#a a 
#1 2 

#$b
#b b b 
#3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could, for example, use a simple `for` loop to manipulate the elements of the list:

```
nms <- names(lst)
for (i in seq_along(lst)) {
  names(lst[[i]]) <- rep(nms[i], length(lst[[i]]))
}
```

This is pretty fast already.

#### Benchmarks

Here is a comparison with the other answers:

```r
forloop <- function() {
  nms <- names(lst)
  for (i in seq_along(lst)) {
    names(lst[[i]]) <- rep(nms[i], length(lst[[i]]))
  }
  lst
}


map_approach <- function() {
  Map(setNames, lst, Map(rep, names(lst), lengths(lst)))
}

ronaks_approach <- function() {
  vals <- rep(names(lst), lengths(lst))
  split(setNames(unlist(lst), vals), vals)
}


res <- bench::mark(
  forloop(),
  map_approach(),
  ronaks_approach(),
  check = TRUE
)
```

And here are the results:

```r
res
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression             min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>        <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 forloop()            3.7µs   4.36µs   216113.    4.26MB     21.6
#> 2 map_approach()        15µs  17.69µs    53871.    3.64KB     21.6
#> 3 ronaks_approach()   50.6µs   57.7µs    16809.   34.62KB     14.4
summary(res, relative = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression          min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>        <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 forloop()          1      1        12.9    1199.       1.50
#> 2 map_approach()     4.05   4.06      3.20      1        1.49
#> 3 ronaks_approach() 13.7   13.2       1         9.51     1
```

As the example is unrealistically small, here is another run with a bigger sample (`lst <- rep(lst, 50000)` and `names(lst) <- make.names(names(lst), unique = TRUE)` since @Ronak's approach needs unique names):

```r
res
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression             min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>        <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 forloop()            185ms    302ms      3.31   781.3KB     8.28
#> 2 map_approach()       507ms    507ms      1.97    1.91MB     3.94
#> 3 ronaks_approach()    654ms    654ms      1.53   26.88MB     0
summary(res, relative = TRUE)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression          min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>        <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 forloop()          1      1         2.17      1         Inf
#> 2 map_approach()     2.74   1.68      1.29      2.50      Inf
#> 3 ronaks_approach()  3.53   2.17      1        35.2       NaN
```

There is no big difference between the answers but it seems my hunch was right that a simple `for` loop is a good approach here.